# how to extract data of a particular date between to date ranges

Tags: php, mysql

we have a mysql table with the below fields

```
employeename,   shift   from date   todate
111aaa,         B,      2018-09-01  2018-09-30
222bbb,         C,      2017-04-01  2030-12-01
```

how can i write a query like when i give particular employee number and particular date like 2018-09-20 it must show his shift as B as the date range fall under about 1st row date range.
pl. help me.

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this;

```
SELECT * FROM employees WHERE employeename = '111aaa' AND fromdate <= '2018-09-02' AND todate >= '2018-09-02' ORDER BY fromdate DESC LIMIT 1
```

This selects an employee who's employname is '111aaa' and where a supplied date '2018-09-02' is between the fromdate and todate on the employee record. It sorts the results with the latest fromdate first, and only returns a single result.

Comment: thank you for your quick reply. we dont give date range in our query. we give only particular date which must check in the table between from date and todate and show the shift

Comment: That’s exactly what the query I posted does. You supply it with a single date and it returns only those rows where the supplied date is between the dates specified on the record.

Comment: thank you after tweaking slightly my coding it worked and i used query of fromdate <= '2018-09-02' AND todate >= '2018-09-02'